# Determine the exact location of the centroid?

Tags: triangles

This is my last question for the day! :P Usually I am good at math but I've been sick for over a year and am now finding it hard to concentrate. :P

Triangle CDE has vertices C(-2,4), D(6,2), and E(-4, -2). Determine the exact location of the centroid of triangle CDE.

I need help with this math question. I tried solving it multiple times but got stuck. :/ Please help. :)
Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that the centroid of a triangle with vertices $(x_a, y_a), (x_b, y_b), (x_c, y_c) $ is

$$ ( \frac{ x_a+x_b+x_c} { 3} , \frac{y_a+y_b+y_c} { 3}). $$

There are many ways to do so. The most basic way is to show that the above point lies on all of the medians.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot.